# Asp.net - how does it handle references to database rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web application I'm building where I have a worker thread that holds a reference to a database row.

I have an outside service that is calling the web application, and depending on user input on their end, is updating rows in the database.

I'd like to check if those database rows have been modified, but I don't want to do it by query, because I'd be a doing the operation many times per second.

So here's my question, will references to the database rows update when another process updates the database? Are these references non-volatile? In the case of the latter, what is the best way to check if a row has been updated?

For clarity:

This object pointer represents a single row in a database table:

```
Callout co = await db.Callouts.FindAsync(id);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "holds a reference to a database row", specifically? Do you mean it keeps a reference to a [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) object?

Comment: I have a table in my Database, for example, called "Shift_Offer". In my worker thread, I hold a reference to a single row in that table, which is described by the 'Shift_Offer' object in my model, which was made by the data scaffolding process. 

This is an asp.net MVC question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "hold reference to a single row in that table."  You couldn't possibly mean this literally. The table itself is on another box and buried deep within a SQL data file.  Do you mean a reference to a domain object which represents a row in that table?  Perhaps you could post some code.

Comment: I just explained to you exactly what I meant. I don't think I could possibly make it any clearer.

Comment: You mean you have an object reference to an object of type "Shift_Offer."  is that it?  and Shift_Offer was generated by Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. And conceptually anyway, it is a reference to a database row.

Comment: You're missing that just because you retrieved some data from a data source doesn't mean it's still tied to that source. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET and everything to do with what technique you're using to access database.

Comment: mason - You just rephrased my question.

Comment: You really should clarify in your question what you're using to access the database.

Comment: It's the LINQ library, as is specified in the tag and the code sample.

Comment: That really is not specific. Are you using LINQ to SQL? LINQ alongside Entity Framework? LINQ with a custom repository built on top of ADO.NET? Don't assume we know what you're doing.

Comment: Well I've also tagged that it's an mvc-5 project, which uses Entity Framework if I understand the underlying tech correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The buzzword you are looking for is [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

While it sounds like you want to roll your own, you may not be aware that the EF can do this for you, if you set it up correctly.

You will need to add the following to your data model:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

In addition you will need to add the [ConcurrencyCheckAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute.aspx) to your data members.

Finally, you will need to write code to handle the [OptimisticConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.optimisticconcurrencyexception.aspx).

A tutorial for doing this with EF can be found [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

If you really don't want to do all that, and just want your app to be notified when a table is modified, you can accomplish that with something like [SqlTableDependency](http://tabledependency.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yes this is more or less what I was looking for, thank you.